# Set cookies from the app to Safari in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, safari

In my app I need to implement next feature: when user logged-in in the app, it (the app) needs to save cookies (or any other data) for certain website to mobile Safari. The goal is to not make user log-in next time when he will open that website in Safari.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/index.html) says that it can't be done on iOS using cookies. Does anybody know any other solution? Required feature of implementation is to make it 'silently' to user, without opening Safari.

**UPDATE**

Is it possible to access app data from mobile Safari and get some callback? For example when user browses website the site sends some callback to the app and gets some response with user' data.

Comment: it can't be done in IOS/mobilesafari, or any other operating system and/or browser for a very good reason : if any application could arbitrarily mess with browser cookies that would be a massive gaping security hole.
This should be done *in the browser*, and *on the site in question*

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but could you open Safari to a special one-time URL from your app which takes user to a page which you host, passing a token which you retrieve from API on same server, with page then validating token and setting cookie? That way authorization is handled on server, and server can set the cookie in the response.

You could do something like this in your app

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myhost.com/myhandler?token=PX2G16BWFKZBQWUKGF3BGRY2Z6BEJ7Z3PMO2GZ6S3R00JVWBVEO6VWBEXNK14IBJ5GKAY5EKBLAHNSAJ8"]];
```

Then page at myhost.com/myhandler would read and validate token, and set cookie on response, and then invalidate the token. You could also add a time limit for how long the token could be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the safari cookies.

> Safari's cookies are not accessible from other apps. Each app is given
>   its own WebKit cache and cookie stores, so while cookies will persist
>   within the same app, they aren't accessible between apps.