# How to share data between browser and my app

Tags: ios, google-chrome, web, xamarin, safari

I'm building chat app for iOS using Xamarin.

My user starts with the browser version of my chat (using their favorite browser) and then can decide to download my app and continue from there.

My question - 
On the web, I create cookie with userID. I need to pass the userID to the app to keep the user in context. How can I do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Depending on the browser, but I'm quite sure that Safari's cookies are not available to other apps, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688712/set-cookies-from-the-app-to-safari-in-ios). You can pass some data via deeplink to your app, like an authentication token, and use that token to fetch conversation history

Comment: The flow is (1) Browser --> (2) App Store --> (3) Open my app. Do you think DL will work?

Comment: once they install the app they will need to go back and click the link